# Two :id in rails route for DELETE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

I have the following rails route

`model_name DELETE model_name/:id/comments/:id(.:format)`

and I was wondering when I call `params[:id]` in the `destroy` method, what `:id` does it take? The first or the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route should be

`DELETE model_name/:model_id/comments/:id(.:format)`

So params[:model_id] will take the first one and params[:id] will take the 2nd one(comment id)

for more details http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Answer (score 0):

params[:id] will take the second id. The first id value can be accessed via params[:model_name_id]

For example with a route like
/posts/1/comments/4

params[:id] = 4
params[:post_id] = 1